# Difference between adding sudo user with adduser or gpasswd

Tags: sudo, users, group, accounts

To add a new sudo user I believe I can call:

```
# to create a new user
sudo adduser newusername
```

and to allow this user to use sudo I can do:

```
sudo adduser newusername sudo
```

or

```
sudo gpasswd -a newusername sudo
```

If this is correct, is there any difference between these commands or reasons to use one over the other for primarily Ubuntu server hardening script, but also trying to be as generic as possible, eg different Linux versions or distribution compatibility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ultimately, Debian's (and therefore Ubuntu's) `adduser` calls `gpasswd`:

```perl
my $gpasswd = &which('gpasswd');                           
&systemcall($gpasswd, '-a',$existing_user,$existing_group);
```

Debian's `adduser` was written with the purpose of being a convenient frontend to a range of utilities (it makes use of, at one step or another, `useradd`, `gpasswd`, `usermod`, `passwd`, `chfn`, and a couple more commands). `adduser` and co. are somewhat distro-specific in nature, being frontend scripts. The one you see is from [Debian](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/adduser/adduser_3.113+nmu3ubuntu3/copyright), while [Slackware](http://docs.slackware.com/slackbook:users) and [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?adduser(8)) (at least) have their own.

I'd expect a consistent interface with the lower level commands like `usermod` and `gpasswd`, since they seem to originate from a common set of tools according to the origins of the package in [Debian](http://pkg-shadow.alioth.debian.org/) (and thereby [Ubuntu](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/s/shadow/shadow_4.1.5.1-1ubuntu9/copyright), [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/shadow/), [Fedora](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/21/x86_64/s/shadow-utils-4.1.5.1-17.fc21.x86_64.html), and [CentOS](http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/centos/6.6/i386/Packages/shadow-utils-4.1.4.2-19.el6.i686.html)), and [Slackware](http://packages.slackware.com/?r=slackware-current&p=shadow-4.2.1-i486-1.txz).

On the other hand, [Debian recommends](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/system-administrator/ch-sysadmin-users.html#s8.2.1) that system administrators use `adduser`, etc.

Comment: This also gave me the idea to open commands in an editor and check the Perl script to see how it works.

Comment: so... you recommend gpasswd? I wonder why debian recommends adduser